# Elastic Search scrolling with NEST and C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using the following code to loop/scroll over all documents in my elastic search box:

```
const string indexName = "bla";
var client = GetClient(indexName);
const int scrollTimeout = 1000;

var initialResponse = client.Search<Document>
    (scr => scr.Index(indexName)
    .From(0)
    .Take(100)
    .MatchAll()
    .Scroll(scrollTimeout))
;

List<XYZ> results;
results = new List<XYZ>();

if (!initialResponse.IsValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialResponse.ScrollId))
throw new Exception(initialResponse.ServerError.Error.Reason);

if (initialResponse.Documents.Any())
results.AddRange(initialResponse.Documents);

var scrollid = initialResponse.ScrollId;
bool isScrollSetHasData = true;
while (isScrollSetHasData)
{
    var loopingResponse = client.Scroll<XYZ>(scrollTimeout, scrollid);

    if (loopingResponse.IsValid)
    {
        results.AddRange(loopingResponse.Documents);
        scrollid = loopingResponse.ScrollId;
    }
    isScrollSetHasData = loopingResponse.Documents.Any();

    // do some amazing stuff
}

client.ClearScroll(new ClearScrollRequest(scrollid));
```

For some reason loopingResponse is empty much sooner than expected - i.e. the scroll finishes. Can someone see something fundamentally wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: What version of NEST & elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: 7.0 thanks for comment

Comment: are you sure that `scrollTimeout` is enough to keep the search context alive? because if not then the response will come back without documents obviously and stop there

Comment: Thanks I have to say that I do not fully understand this parameter. Where exactly is the doc? There are so many removed and different pages for different versions. Is this in millisecond btw? Could I set it to some maximum? Thanks!

Comment: to get rid of confusion I usually do something like `.Scroll(new Time(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)))`

Comment: and yes, that's milliseconds: [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/CommonOptions/TimeUnit/Time.cs)

Comment: Great thanks will try tomorrow.

Comment: @AndreyBorisko this seems to work - maybe you can post answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I think `scrollTimeout` could be the problem. Usually scroll is used for big chunks of data to be returned and 1000ms is not enough to keep the search context alive between requests. You could try to increase it to several minutes to find the best number for your case:

```
var scrollTimeout = new Time(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
```

or according to [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/CommonOptions/TimeUnit/Time.cs) you could use Time units (micros, nanos, ms, s, m, h, and d):

```
var response = client.Search<Document>(scr => scr.Index(indexName)
    ...
    .Scroll("3m")
    );
```