# getting document attribute values without scrolling - elastic search next

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have indexed documents with this simplified structure:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string x { get; set; }

}
```

I am searching them like this:

```
var initialResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s.From(0)
    .Size(100).Scroll(scrollTimeout)
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchPhrase(c => c
            .Field(p => p.Attachment.Content)
            .Analyzer("standard")
            .Boost(1.1)
            .Query(searchTerm)
        )));
```

and then loop over the documents (more code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270216/elastic-search-scrolling-with-nest-and-c-sharp?)). This obviously take time and I wonder, if I could obtain all Ids or even better x values of the matched documents in one payload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch has a `index.max_result_window` setting with a default value of 10,000.

That's the max number of documents you can retrieve in a single request. If you want to get more than that - you'll need to use `scroll` or `search_after` API, as you do already.

Comment: thanks. however, can one aggregate server side and just get the aggregated payload?

Comment: @cs0815 I believe you cannot do it. You'll have to do it on your client-side.

Comment: Thanks. wow, somehow I do not see the point of ES then. Let us say I just want the number of document containing a (fuzzy) term?

Comment: In that case, you could issue a [count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) query and it would tell you the exact number of documents it found with that term. As for not seeing point for ES, ES being a search engine is optimized to return top-k documents, hence the limit :)